# What is "Total Possible" in Undergraduate Grade Point Average

Tags: undergraduate, university, gpa

While working on a university application, I found the following, please see the image below. Here, what should I write in **Total Possible** field? Could you briefly explain with an example? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would almost certainly be the maximum for "full marks" in your courses. In the US it is usually 4.0 (sometimes 4.5). I think in India it is usually 10.0. Other places will vary. So, in the US GPA is something like 3.7/4.0, making 4.0 the total possible.

It seems odd, however, that they also want the 4.0 equivalent.

Comment: The equivalent can take into account systems that are more different, such as having better grades corresponding to lower numbers.

Comment: @Anyon, the world is a big place.